# When would a instance variable be used and when would a property be used?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In a header file such as this, when would an instance variable be used and when would a property be used?

**Do they have to have the same name?**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BlueViewController;
@class YellowViewController;

@interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController {
    YellowViewController *yellowViewController;
    BlueViewController *blueViewController;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) YellowViewController *yellowViewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) BlueViewController *blueViewController;

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `@property` declaration simply creates accessor methods for an ivar. So properties don't really have names, only the accessor methods do; and these don't have to have the same name as the ivar. In fact, they don't even have to have a corresponding ivar.

You can change the names of the methods using the `getter` and `setter` decorators like this:

```
@property (assign, getter=isValid) BOOL valid;
```

Now, as I said, a `@property` declaration simply creates accessor methods for an ivar. So you use properties when you want accessor methods. Here are a few reasons why you might want accessor methods:

1. Encapsulation (a property might be advertised as a different type than the ivar, or might not even have an ivar)
2. Related state changes (change another ivar or invoke a method when an ivar is modified)
3. You can use the `retain` decorator and `@synthesize` the property to get much simpler memory management
4. You can use `atomic` decorator (or simply not use the `nonatomic` decorator, since properties are atomic by default) to create atomic properties

Here's an example to demonstrate points 1 and 2:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    @private
    int flags;
    // Humpty and Dumpty are mutually exclusive
    BOOL humpty;
    BOOL dumpty;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL flagA;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL flagB;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL humpty;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL dumpty;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isClean) BOOL clean;

@end

@implementation Foo

@synthesize humpty, dumpty; // Synthesize the getters, but provide the setters

- (void)setHumpty:(BOOL)value {
    if(value && dumpty)
        dumpty = NO;

    humpty = value;
}

- (void)setDumpty:(BOOL)value {
    if(value && humpty)
        humpty = NO;

    dumpty = value;
}

- (BOOL)flagA {
    return flags & 0x01;
}

- (void)setFlagA:(BOOL)value {
    if(value)
        flags |= 0x01;
    else
        flags &= ~0x01;
}

- (BOOL)flagB {
    return flags & 0x02;
}

- (void)setFlagB:(BOOL)value {
    if(value)
        flags |= 0x02;
    else
        flags &= ~0x02;
}

// Making this a property doesn't really make sense
// but I'm just trying to demonstrate what you can do
// with properties
- (BOOL)isClean {
    return flags == 0;
}

@end
```

Comment: +1 For clarity and nice example. Possibly the `clean` ivar muddies the water a touch?

Comment: @walkytalky: yeah, I noticed I didn't even use it (I had something else in mind), so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

They can have the same name, although they don't have to. Indeed, it's not required for the externally-visible property to correspond exactly to a single instance variable at all. Such a correspondence *is* expected if you're going to `@synthesize` the accessor methods, but there are quite legitimate reasons for creating the methods manually and making them do something other than just getting/setting a matching ivar.

Instance variables are normally not accessible from the outside world, so all external access has to be via the property methods. (It is possible to declare ivars `@public`, but this is rarely a good idea.)

From within the object, whether you access as properties or instance variables depends on what the properties actually are and what you're doing with them.

For simple synthesized properties it is common to use the accessors (either explicitly using `[self setXxx]` or using the dot notation as `self.xxx`) except within `dealloc` (and possibly `init`, depending on who you ask).

In more complex cases, you really have to think about what it is you are trying to achieve. But if you've gone to the trouble of making them properties you probably want whatever functionality is encapsulated in the accessor methods to be called most of the time.

At any rate, read the [properties documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProperties.html) to get a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the properties for all your external access to provide [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)), it's up to you whether you want to use them internally though, i think it's a matter of taste.

By using the properties from outside of your class you can for example do some lazy [loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) and it becomes a lot easier to make any potential API changes by providing deprecation warnings in the getters/setters.